# How can pass parameter in RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC asp.net.

This is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult ingredientEdit(int id) {
    ProductFormulation productFormulation = db.ProductFormulation.Single(m => m.ID == id);
    return View(productFormulation);
}

//
// POST: /Admin/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ingredientEdit(ProductFormulation productFormulation) {
    productFormulation.CreatedBy = "Admin";
    productFormulation.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    productFormulation.ModifiedBy = "Admin";
    productFormulation.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    productFormulation.IsDeleted = false;
    productFormulation.UserIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.ProductFormulation.Attach(productFormulation);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(productFormulation, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        **return RedirectToAction("ingredientIndex");**
    }
    return View(productFormulation);
}
```

I want to pass id to `ingredientIndex` action. How can I do this?

I want to use this id **public ActionResult ingredientEdit(int id)** which is coming from another page.   actually I don't have `id` in second action, please suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 29):

```
return RedirectToAction("IngredientIndex", new { id = id });
```

Update

First I would rename IngredientIndex and IngredientEdit to just Index and Edit and place them in IngredientsController, instead of AdminController, you can have an Area named Admin if you want.

```
//
// GET: /Admin/Ingredients/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    // Pass content to view.
    return View(yourObjectOrViewModel);
}

//
// POST: /Admin/Ingredients/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ProductFormulation productFormulation)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid()) {
        // Do stuff here, like saving to database.
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id });
    }

    // Not valid, show content again.
    return View(yourObjectOrViewModel)
}
```

Comment: how can i use value of "id" in  [HttpPost] action.?

Comment: Look at the example above. If you are editing your fifth item (/Edit/5), it will automatically map it to id (int) when you POST (with standard routes and so on...).

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
return RedirectToAction("IngredientIndex", new { id = productFormulation.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
return RedirectToAction("ingredientIndex?Id=" + id);
```

Comment: You will have to pass the id along every view